# Firestore set()/update() methods are setting fields in random position

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular5, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a one on one chat application. Here is the conversations data model :

```
user_messages (collection)
  user1 (document)
    talksTo (collection)
      user2 (document)
        randomKey {
          content: "hello"
          }
        randomKey {
          content: "how are you?"
          }
      user3 (document)
      user4 (document)
```

Basically, each time an user sends a message to another users, it stores a new object gathering all the informations I need.

chat.service.ts

```
sendChat(message: Message) {
    const id = this.afs.createId();
    const content = {
        [id]: {
            ...message
        }
    }

    this.afs.doc(`/user-messages/${message.userFromId}/talksTo/${message.userToId}`).set(content, { merge: true });

}
```

Then I retrive these conversations like so:

chat.service.ts

```
async getChats(userTwoId: string) {
    return await this.afs.doc(`/user-messages/${DataService.authenticatedUserProfile.$key}/talksTo/${userTwoId}`);
}
```

Then I'm populating the messageList array in order to use `*ngFor` and display content:

message.ts

```
async ionViewWillLoad() {

// Retrive every messages we have with the person we are talking to
// this.messageList = await this.chat.getChats(this.profile.$key);
const data = await this.chat.getChats(this.profile.$key);
data.valueChanges()
  .subscribe(data => {
    if (data) {
      this.messageList = (<any>Object).values(data);
      console.log(this.messageList);
    }
  })
}
```

The problem is, when trying to update a new field to a document (with `sendChat()`'s method), it's setting the new field in a random position within the document. That causes an issue when I want to subscribe to this document as it wont populate `messageList` array the same way each time, meaning the conversation will be mixed up all the time. And it's happens each time the observable is being triggered, meaning each time user is sending a new message.

How can I manage to store a new field without breaking the current order, so I'm guessing storing in at the very end/beggining of the document's fields?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maps in Cloud Firestore (and many programming languages) do not guarantee consistent ordering of fields in the Map.

One suggestion to work around this is to prepend a `timestamp` to the random key, then always make sure to sort the document fields before displaying.